# wiring issues in ceiling light

Tags: wiring

I have a ceiling light that was knocked off the ceiling blowing the circuit. It did not blow the breaker, but everything on that breaker is not working. I replaced the breaker with no change. Any suggestions on what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Check to see what is in the ceiling fan box. Sounds like when the ceiling fan got ripped out, it ripped out the wire nuts that connected it.

If this was the first light on the circuit, then there were probably 3 wires in each wire nut -- source, lamp, and next light on circuit.  If you disconnected the source->next wires, it would explain your problem.

Comment: Did you wire up a new light fixture? Is it wired the same way as the one that was damaged? As @gbronner mentions, the wiring in that box could supply power to fixtures "downstream".